# ALL query in Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I need to translate the following SQL to Ecto Query DSL.

```
SELECT otc.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN one_time_codes otc ON u.id = otc.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN one_time_code_invalidations otci ON otci.one_time_code_id = otc.id
WHERE u.id = 3 AND
      otc.code = 482693 AND
      otci.inserted_at IS NULL AND
      otc.inserted_at > all(SELECT otc.inserted_at
                            FROM one_time_codes otc2
                            WHERE otc2.user_id = 3) AND
      otc.inserted_at > (now() - '180 seconds'::interval);
```

In the third `AND` statement of `WHERE` clause, notice there is an `ALL` query. Ecto seems to not have corresponding function in `Ecto.Query.API`.

How to apply such aggregate? What is the correct way to implement this, though it could be implemented by having a lookup on debug logs of the Ecto, do you have another idea (or suggestion)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecto does not allow subqueries in expressions, and you're right that there's no `all` in Ecto's Query API, but you can use `fragment` like this:

```
where: ...
  and otc.inserted_at > fragment("all(SELECT otc.inserted_at FROM one_time_codes otc2 WHERE otc2.user_id = ?", 3)
  and ...
```

Comment: Thanks again :). How do you pass the superquery parameters in fragments, for example, you need to refer `u in User` from a join query found in superquery?

Comment: Does something like this work for you: `join: u in User, ..., where: fragment("? = ?", u.id, 10)`?

Comment: Wow, neat. Thank you.